# Image encryption, why it can't decrypt?

Tags: java, image, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt an image using ACM and henon, encryption is successful, but it can't be decrypted. The problem is (problem decrypt is after XORing pixel value, it can't restore it to initial position).

encryption scheme according to this :
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5054653&contentType=Conference+Publications&queryText%3Dimage+encryption+henon

Encryption step is:

1. Read image
2. Pixel extraction
3. Shuffle pixel using ACM
4. Generate henon pseudorandom
5. Rounded henon pseudo random
6. XORing shufle pixel vaue with henon pseudorandom
7. Write image
8. Cipher image done

Decryption step is:

1. Read cipher image
2. Pixel extraction
3. Generate henon pseudorandom
4. Rounded henon pseudo random
5. XORing shufle pixel vaue with henon pseudorandom
6. Restore pixel position using inverse ACM
7. Write image
8. image restored

Thanks.

Encryption code below:

```
  img = ImageIO.read(new File("5x5grayscale.bmp"));    
  Raster pixel = img.getData();               
  pxl = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
  pxl2 = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];           

  for(int j=0;j<img.getHeight();j++){ 
    for(int i=0;i<img.getWidth();i++){                 
      pxl[i][j]= pixel.getSample(i, j, 0);  
      pxl2[i][j]= pixel.getSample(i, j, 0);  
    }                                                                       
  }           

  // shuffe pixel ACM iterration 1
  System.out.println("shuffle iteration  1");
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){                 
      x[xx]=(1*i + c*j)%5;            
      y[xx]=(d*i + e*j)%5; 
      //System.out.println("-new coordinate ="+i+" , "+j+"="+x[xx]+","+y[xx]);
      xx++; 
    }
  }

  //shuffle pixel ACM 2 sd 10
  for(int k=0;k<9;k++){
    System.out.println("shuffle iteration "+(k+2));
    xx=0; 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++){                 
        xtemp = x[xx];
        ytemp = y[xx];
        x[xx] = (1*xtemp + c*ytemp) % 5;
        y[xx] = (d*xtemp + e*ytemp) % 5;   

        System.out.println("-new coordinate="+i+" , "+j+"="+x[xx]+","+y[xx]);
        xx++; 
      }
    }              
  } 

  xx=0; 
  for (int a =0;a<5;a++){
    for(int b=0;b<5;b++){
      pxl[a][b]= pxl2[x[xx]][y[xx]];
      xx++;
      //System.out.println(pxl[a][b]);
    }
  }

  System.out.println("===================================henon============================");
  double k[] = new  double[102]; 
  int inter[] = new int [102];

  k[0] = 0.01;
  k[1] = 0.02; 
  double a=1.4;
  double b=0.3;


  System.out.println("generate pseudo random");
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){                       
    k[i+2] =1-a*(Math.pow(k[i+1], 2))+b*k[i];
    // System.out.println(k[i]);            
  }  

  System.out.println("after rounded");
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    inter[i]= (int) Math.round((k[i]*65536)%256);
    if(inter[i]<0){
      inter[i]=inter[i]+256;
    }
    //    System.out.println(inter[i]);
  }

  System.out.println("setelah xor");
  System.out.println("setelah xor");
  cipher = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
  int z=0;  
  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getWidth();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getHeight();jj++){
      cipher[ii][jj]=inter[z]^pxl[ii][jj];
      // System.out.println(cipher[ii][jj]);
      z++;
    }
  }

  image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);          
  WritableRaster write = image.getRaster();                 

  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getHeight();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getWidth();jj++){          
      write.setSample(jj, ii, 0,cipher[jj][ii] );   
    }  
  }  

  ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("acmhenonenkrip5x5.bmp"));  
  System.out.println("cipher image done");           
}
```

Decrypt code below:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
  int c =2;
  int d = 2;
  int e = c*d+1;
  int x[]= new int[100];
  int y[]= new int[100];
  int xx=0;
  int xtemp;
  int ytemp;
  int sama=1;
  BufferedImage img ;
  BufferedImage image = null;
  int [][]pxl = null ;
  int [][]pxl2 = null ;
  int [][]cipher=null;

  img = ImageIO.read(new File("acmhenonenkrip5x5.bmp"));    
  Raster pixel = img.getData();     

  pxl = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
  pxl2 = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];


  for(int j=0;j<img.getHeight();j++){ 
    for(int i=0;i<img.getWidth();i++){                 
      pxl[i][j]= pixel.getSample(i, j, 0);  
      pxl2[i][j]= pixel.getSample(i, j, 0);  
    }                                                                       
  }   

  System.out.println("===================================henon============================");
  double k[] = new  double[30];            int inter[] = new int [30];

  k[0] = 0.01;
  k[1] = 0.02; 
  double a=1.4;
  double b=0.3;


  System.out.println("generate pseudo random");
  for(int i=0;i<27;i++){                       
    k[i+2] =1-a*(Math.pow(k[i+1], 2))+b*k[i];
    // System.out.println(k[i]);            
  }  

  System.out.println("after rounded");
  for(int i=0;i<27;i++){
    inter[i]= (int) Math.round((k[i]*65536)%256);
    if(inter[i]<0){
      inter[i]=inter[i]+256;
    }
    // System.out.println(inter[i]);
  }

  System.out.println("after  xor");
  cipher = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
  int z=0;  
  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getWidth();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getHeight();jj++){
      cipher[ii][jj]=inter[z]^pxl[ii][jj];
      // System.out.println(cipher[ii][jj]);
      z++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println("===================================inverseacm============================");

  System.out.println("decrypt iteration1");

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){      
      x[xx]=((e*i) + (-c*j))%5; 
      if(x[xx]<0){
        x[xx]=x[xx]+5;
      }
      y[xx]=((-d*i) + (1*j))%5;  
      if(y[xx]<0){
        y[xx]=y[xx]+5;
      }
      // System.out.println(xx+"-new coordinate ="+i+","+j+"="+x[xx]+","+y[xx]);
      xx++; 
    }    
  }

  for(int iter=0;iter<9;iter++){
    System.out.println("decrypt iteration "+(iter+2));
    xx=0;  
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++){     
        xtemp = x[xx];
        ytemp = y[xx];
        x[xx]=((e*xtemp) + (-c*ytemp))%5; 
        if(x[xx]<0){
            x[xx]=x[xx]+5;
        }
        y[xx]=((-d*xtemp) + (1*ytemp))%5;  
        if(y[xx]<0){
          y[xx]=y[xx]+5;
        }
        // System.out.println(xx+"-new coordinate ="+i+","+j+"="+x[xx]+","+y[xx]);
        xx++; 
      }          
    }
  }    

  xx=0; 
  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getWidth();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getHeight();jj++){
      System.out.println("cip"+cipher[x[xx]][y[xx]]); //tracing pixel value of cipher
      xx++;     
    }            
  } 

  xx=0; 
  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getWidth();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getHeight();jj++){
      System.out.println("pxl"+pxl[x[xx]][y[xx]]); //tracing pixel value of pxl
      xx++;     
    }
  }

  image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);          
  WritableRaster write = image.getRaster();                 

  for(int ii=0;ii<img.getHeight();ii++){
    for(int jj=0;jj<img.getWidth();jj++){          
      write.setSample(jj, ii, 0,cipher[jj][ii] );                             
    }  
  }  

  ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("acmhenondekrip5x5.bmp"));  
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to this paper? http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1917638 and are you using this (instead of something like RC4) out of idle curiosity, or another reason?

Comment: Why do you use such a strange encryption scheme?

Comment: i'm already add the references

Comment: Your shuffle code only affects the leading diagonal, i might be missing the point but it looks borked to me.

Comment: Can you provide the first few lines of the encryption program, too?

Comment: Have you checked here you start getting differences? If you compare they bytes you save, are they the same as the ones you read? Are the reversed ACM same as before ACM? Are the values after reverse XOR same as before original XOR? If you hardcode expected reverse ACM, does the rest of the algorithm work? It probably helps if you can pinpoint which part in the process breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate each stage into two methods: one to do and another to undo. Then you should write a short set of tests that generates thousands of random inputs and on each, it checks `input.equals(undoIt(doIt(input)));` or something like that.

If any of the tests fails, you'll know where to start looking.